# Where do I find linux commandline httpd exit codes?

Tags: httpd

I am building an api through ssh and it relies on the exit codes of all individual commands.

I've found all exit status codes and their meaning for commands like:
useradd, userdel, mkdir and others, but I am missing a list of all exit codes and related status messages from **httpd**. Does anybody know where I can find those?

Comment: You want to run httpd as a command through an api?

Comment: yes, httpd reload. And on error I'd like to catch an exit code and extract it's message. My api is an ssh api, between to servers on a local network.

Comment: I don't have an Apache install handy, but the docs say you should use apachectl  instead (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html). "The apachectl script returns a 0 exit value on success, and >0 if an error occurs. For more details, view the comments in the script."

Comment: I just ran: httpd reload 2>/dev/null && echo 0 || echo $?        It seems like it just exits 0 or 1.  So I guess I will have to stop replying on exitcodes for some commands. I think I will read the response line for line for some commands.